# Reverse position of entries in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Here I have an extract from my pandas dataframe which is survey data with two datetime fields. It appears that some of the start times and end times were filled in the wrong position in the survey. Here is an example from my dataframe. The start and end time in the 8th row, I suspect were entered the wrong way round.

Just to give context, I generated the third column like this:

```
df_time['trip_duration'] =  df_time['tripEnd_time'] - df_time['tripStart_time']
```

The three columns are in timedelta64 format.

Here is the top of my dataframe:

```
tripStart_time  tripEnd_time    trip_duration
1   22:30:00    23:15:00    00:45:00
2   11:00:00    11:30:00    00:30:00
3   09:00:00    09:15:00    00:15:00
4   13:30:00    14:25:00    00:55:00
5   09:00:00    10:15:00    01:15:00
6   12:00:00    12:15:00    00:15:00
7   08:00:00    08:30:00    00:30:00
8   11:00:00    09:15:00    -1 days +22:15:00
9   14:00:00    14:30:00    00:30:00
10  14:55:00    15:20:00    00:25:00
```

What I am trying to do is, loop through these two columns, and for each time 'tripEnd_time' is less than 'tripStart_time' swap the positions of these two entries. So in the case of row 8 above, I would make tripStart_time = tripEnd_time and tripEnd_time = tripStart_time.

I am not quite sure the best way to approach this. Should I use nested for loop where i compare each entry in the two columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
df_time['trip_duration'] = (df_time['tripEnd_time'] - df_time['tripStart_time']).abs()
print (df_time)
1        22:30:00     23:15:00      00:45:00
2        11:00:00     11:30:00      00:30:00
3        09:00:00     09:15:00      00:15:00
4        13:30:00     14:25:00      00:55:00
5        09:00:00     10:15:00      01:15:00
6        12:00:00     12:15:00      00:15:00
7        08:00:00     08:30:00      00:30:00
8        11:00:00     09:15:00      01:45:00
9        14:00:00     14:30:00      00:30:00
10       14:55:00     15:20:00      00:25:00
```

What is same like:

```
a = df_time['tripEnd_time'] - df_time['tripStart_time']
b = df_time['tripStart_time'] - df_time['tripEnd_time']
mask = df_time['tripEnd_time'] > df_time['tripStart_time']

df_time['trip_duration'] =  np.where(mask, a, b)
print (df_time)
   tripStart_time tripEnd_time trip_duration
1        22:30:00     23:15:00      00:45:00
2        11:00:00     11:30:00      00:30:00
3        09:00:00     09:15:00      00:15:00
4        13:30:00     14:25:00      00:55:00
5        09:00:00     10:15:00      01:15:00
6        12:00:00     12:15:00      00:15:00
7        08:00:00     08:30:00      00:30:00
8        11:00:00     09:15:00      01:45:00
9        14:00:00     14:30:00      00:30:00
10       14:55:00     15:20:00      00:25:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch column values on selected rows:

```
df_time.loc[df_time['tripEnd_time'] < df_time['tripStart_time'],
            ['tripStart_time', 'tripEnd_time']] = df_time.loc[
                df_time['tripEnd_time'] < df_time['tripStart_time'],
                ['tripEnd_time', 'tripStart_time']].values
```